# WPF ComboBox for Interface types

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently building an application that contains a structure similar to this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string property1 {get;set;}
    public string property2 {get;set;}

    public ISomeInterface interfaceProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Which then has several different classes defined that implement ISomeInterface.

Is there a way to represent the interfaceProperty as a combobox of choices that would let me change the type that is stored there, without resorting to wiring that all up in the code behind?

Extra wrinkle, I would also like to show some databound textboxes to configure various properties in the selected type, which would change when the type is changed, is this possible?

Comment: Reflection will take care of the combo box, just populate a collection based on the results. As for creating instances via UI, you can use a data template selector based on actual type of the property. I don't have code to hand so offering this as a comment as a possible pointer.

Comment: You mean you want a combo box that would let you choose which instance of a class (form all classes that implement the interface) is stored by the property?

Comment: @ZivS Yes pretty much that exactly. Now that I think about it some more I could have a list of ISomeInterface classes that it bound to the combobox.

Comment: You should follow what @kidshaw wrote, if you have any issues with that ask a more specific question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to represent the interfaceProperty as a combobox of choices that would let me change the type that is stored there, without resorting to wiring that all up in the code behind?

Maybe, depending on what you actually want to do. If you simply want to bind a collection of existing objects to the `ComboBox` as the selection options, that should work fine. But obviously in that case, if you are using this UI with more than one instance of your `ViewModel` type, each instance would wind up with the same `ISomeInterface` object for a given implementation type. This may or may not be acceptable.

If you want to automatically detect all available implementations of `ISomeInterface` and populate the `ComboBox` with the types themselves, creating a new instance for the `ViewModel` each time the selected implementation changes, then no…that's going to require some code-behind.

If you do want unique object instances, but are okay with manually specifying the options, then you could do it with e.g. a collection of factory delegates, or implementation of `IValueConverter` (e.g. to convert a `string` or `Type` value from the `ComboBox` to a new instance of the desired type).

Unfortunately, your question is light on requirements, so it's hard to know what would work for you. There are lots of options, and enumerating them all would be "too broad" for Stack Overflow.

> I would also like to show some databound textboxes to configure various properties in the selected type, which would change when the type is changed, is this possible?

Sure. Just declare appropriate `DataTemplate` resources for the different types you want to handle, and use `ContentPresenter` with the `Content` bound to the instance of the type you want to display.

Comment: Hi Peter, I went with binding to a list of strings (generated from the type names), and then using a valueconverter to convert that into a usable instance of they appropriate type (and back) in the bound property. Very similar to one of your suggestions, so I'm giving you the checkmark. Also, a clear description of what to do with the second part is nice. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. Please see [this answer on the "DataTemplates in WPF"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9133495/) post for a more detailed explanation of the use of `DataTemplate` for your scenario.